# Libgdx ClickListener without declaring Stage

Tags: libgdx

I wants to use clicklisterner without creating stage. My codes goes as:

```
ClickListener ck = new ClickListener(
 @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            handleClick(event);
            return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        });
Image button = new Image(buttonTexture);
button.addListerner(ck);


handleClick(Event event){
if(event.getListenerActor==button)
{
 System.out.print('pressed');
 }
}
```

This codes do not work unless i use stage. Just out of curiosity is there any optional clicklistener usage which does not involve in declaring stage so that i can minimize my codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ClickListener` is an `EventListener` that are intend to receive events by scene2d.

`Stage` is an **inputprocessor** that receives input events and fire them on the appropriate actors.

If you don't want to use Stage(scene2d inputprocessor), use own `InputProcessor` or `InputAdapter`(just an adapter class).

An `InputProcessor` is used to receive input events from the keyboard and the touch screen (mouse on the desktop). For this it has to be registered with the `Input.setInputProcessor(InputProcessor)` method. It will be called each frame before the call to `ApplicationListener.render()`.